# Como importar uma biblioteca externa no REACT.JS

Tags: javascript, react, biblioteca, importação

Estou tentando importar uma biblioteca externa direto do browser no REACT.JS, o que seria no HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bibliotecahipotetica..."></script>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso, por favor ?

Comment: onde você está tentando importar?. Importações por html devem ser feitas dentro do `index.html`,e não dentro de componentes. Esta pergunta já foi respondida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868092/how-to-add-external-library-to-reactjs) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354071/how-to-import-external-javascript-in-reactjs). Isso te ajuda?

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro tem que instalar a lib utilizando por exemplo npm.

`npm install nome_lib`

Depois no código use

`import RecursoDaLib from 'name_lib';`

Por exemplo se quiser adicionar a biblioteca do RxJS ao React, vc primeiro deve executar o `npm install rxjs` via linha de comando dentro do projeto, posteriormente vá até o arquivo JS onde quer utilizar os recursos da biblioteca e faça o import, `import { of } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Então... Essa é a questão, a biblioteca que estou tentando usar não está no NPM / Yarn . Estou integrando API de pagamento recorrente do PagSeguro, e essa é uma biblioteca específica deles que eles fornecem na documentação, preciso dela para gerar um token em cima dos dados do cartão de crédito, porque os dados não são enviados diretamente na chamada...

Comment: Você pode me dizer qual biblioteca é? me mandar o link etc, talvez eu consiga melhor lhe ajudar dessa forma. As vezes se o pacote não estiver publicado no npm mas estiver usando o npm para buildar, você consegue importa-lo via package.json através da URL do repositório.

Veja https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install

```npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>```
```npm install <git repo url>```

Comment: Bom dia Derik! A biblioteca é essa https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js

Comment: Olá Lucas, desculpa não conseguir te ajudar, o caso que vc descreveu aparentemente se trata de importar um arquivo js simples em um projeto React, o código do link que vc enviou não é empacotado em um modulo js. Pode existir alguns caminhos para você importar e utilizar esse arquivo JS em seu projeto, veja o link a seguir: https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668. Nele contem algumas formas que variam de acordo com os tipos de componente (Class ou Function) que você está utilizando. Espero que consiga resolver

Comment: Obrigado Derik! Vou dar uma olhada....